# Find correlation of rows in dataframe with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a panda dataframe with this structure and I would like to get as output a table containing only valueus where the Pearson correlation is higher than 0.8.

Input table:

```
Date         Word   Position
01/01/2020   dog    2.2
01/01/2020   cat    3.4
01/01/2020   pig    4
01/01/2020   cow    3
01/02/2020   dog    3.2
01/02/2020   cat    4.4
01/02/2020   pig    4
01/02/2020   cow    3
01/03/2020   dog    3
01/03/2020   cat    4
01/03/2020   pig    4.5
..........
```

Desired output:

```
Word1    Word2  Correlation
cat      dog    0.8
pig      cat    0.9
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to pivot the dataFrame to make 'pig', 'dog' and 'cat' into separate columns.

Alternative to pivot you can use `groupby` or use filters to extract the (date, position) pairs for each animal in `df.Word.unique()`.

That's for splitting the data by animal.
Second step is to use `numpy.correrrelate(df[col1].values, df[col2].values)` for each combination of (col1, col2) in the animals.